# I am facing a trouble while loading the application due to insufficient storage in the virtual device app is crashed and getting closed immediately?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

*I am building a application in android which is mostly of pdf and documents in it*
**May i know how to resolve this issue?**
**May i know how to load ,view all documents from less storage **

Comment: okay try to remove other installed apps

Comment: No apps are installed